# Why do I get wrong mathematical results when using scanner class and delimiters for getting a double in Java?

Tags: java, try-catch, java.util.scanner, user-input, csv

I am writing a program where I have to get a user input, saved as a double. The user must be able to put it using both ',' and '.' as a delimiter - however they want. I tried using useDelimiter which works only partially - it does indeed accept both values (e.g 4.5 and 4,5) but when I later use the entered value in a mathematical equation, I get wrong results - it seems to round the user input down to the closest integer and as an effect no matter whether I enter, 4 or 4.5 or 4,5 or 4.8 etc., I get the same result, which is actually only true to 4.
Does anyone happen to know why it doesn't work?

```
  double protectiveResistor=0;                //must be a double, required by my teacher
  double voltage= 5;    
  System.out.println("Please provide the resistance.");
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
        sc.useDelimiter("(\\p{javaWhitespace}|\\.|,)");

        try
        {
            protectiveResistor=sc.nextDouble();
        }
        catch(InputMismatchException exception)
        {
            System.out.println("Wrong input!");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        if (protectiveResistor<0){
            System.err.println("Wrong input!");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        
        double current = (double)voltage/protectiveResistor;
        double power = (double)current*current*protectiveResistor;
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The `useDelimiter` method is for telling the `Scanner` what character will separate the numbers from each other.  It's not for specifying what character will be the decimal point.  So with your code, if the user enters either `4.5` or `4,5`, the `Scanner` will see that as two separate inputs, `4` and `5`.

Unfortunately, the `Scanner` doesn't have the facility to let you specify two different characters as decimal separators.  The only thing you can really do is scan the two numbers separately, then join them together into a decimal number afterwards.  You will want to scan them as `String` values, so that you don't lose any zeroes after the decimal point.

Answer (score 1):

What useDelimiter() does is split the input on the specified delimiter.
As an example, if you have the input of `4,5`, the following code will print "4".

```
Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
sc.useDelimiter(",");
System.out.println(sc.next())
```

If you also want to print the second part, after the ',', you need to add another line to get the next value, which would in this example print
"4
5":

```
Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
sc.useDelimiter(",");
System.out.println(sc.next())
System.out.println(sc.next())
```

In your code you can do it like this:

```
Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
sc.useDelimiter("(\\p{javaWhitespace}|\\.|,)");

try
{
    String firstPart = "0";
    String secondPart = "0";
    if (sc.hasNext()) {
        firstPart = sc.next();
    }
    if (sc.hasNext()) {
        secondPart = sc.next();
    }
    protectiveResistor = Double.parseDouble(firstPart + "." + secondPart)
}
// Rest of your code here
```

What this code does is split the input on whitespace, '.' and ','. For a floating point value you expect one part before the decimal point and one after it. Therefore, you expect the scanner to have split the input in two parts. These two parts are assigned to two variables, `firstPart` and `secondPart`. In the last step, the two parts are brought together with the '.' as decimal point, as expected by Java and parsed back into a variable of type Double.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I've updated my answer to use next() instead of nextDouble() which should solve this issue

Comment: Looks much better now.